# Emacs on Windows. Dired - no sorting. Unrecognized symbols

Tags: dired, microsoft-windows, org-capture, sorting

Set up Doom Emacs on windows. Works fine but in Dired i have unrecognized symbols and also in org-capture. Sorting in dired does not work either. Any ideas? Latest Emacs.

[image: Dired on windows problem]

Comment: What are the unrecognized symbols?

Comment: @NickD I think with "unrecognized symbols" he is referring to the escape sequences `\361\345\355` present in the column next to the one that shows the size of the files in human readable format. I think those escape sequences are supposed to show icons.

Comment: @Roman Smirnov, coiuld you please provide the value of the variable `dired-listing-switches`?

Comment: Those symbols are russian month name.
dired-listing-switches are set to "-ahl -v --group-directories-first"
I tried to change fonts - no success. Probably encoding problem somewhere?

Comment: @jio210: yes, you are right - I can see them now that I clicked on the image, but my eyes are not good enough to resolve them in the small version included in the question. Thanks!

Comment: This is what happens when i try to save journal entry from capture:

Comment: These default coding systems were tried to encode text
in the buffer ‘journal.org’:
  (undecided-dos (77 . 4194254) (78 . 4194282) (79 . 4194290) (80 . 4194303) (81
  . 4194273) (82 . 4194288) (83 . 4194300) (100 . 4194295) (101 . 4194277) (102
  . 4194290) (103 . 4194274)) (utf-8-dos (77 . 4194254) (78 . 4194282) (79 .
  4194290) (80 . 4194303) (81 . 4194273) (82 . 4194288) (83 . 4194300) (100 .
  4194295) (101 . 4194277) (102 . 4194290) (103 . 4194274))
However, each of them encountered characters it couldn’t encode:
 undecided-dos cannot encode these: utf-8-dos cannot encode these: